# Using content as datasource of front-end

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm really new to Umbraco and I need some direction.

Let's take this simple case:

I need the **end user** to be able to post items to the site (for instance an item may be an advertisement)

I need the **end user** to search for such items posted by other end users based on some filtering.

I need the **editor** of the site to be able to define some predefined values or lists that can be used in the items' properties and in the search filters.

For instance, an item property may be the *City* or *Advertisment Type* etc.

- I need the **editor** to be able to add or remove *Cities* and *Advertisment Types* from the umbraco backoffice (I would assume that *Cities* or *Ad types* are considered Content for the Umbraco CMS)
- I need to be able to present those values in front-end (*as options of a select element in the ad post page or the search filter, for instance*)

**What I have done:**

I created a document type named "**Advertismenet Type**". Not supporting this type in root node, and with no template.
I added a property to that type named "**Advertisment Type Name**". That would be the description of that option.

The next thing I would like to do is to start adding Advertisment Types in the system. I went to Content and tried to add an Advertisment Type, but was unable to. The reason: It's not allowed to the root node. But why would it be? I just want to enter some values in the system, I don't want to create pages out of them. **How would I add such content from the backoffice?**

After I add ad types, I want to see them in the front-end select element for ad types. **How to I render them?**

Comment: You can create another root node and call it Settings and let your editor create there the Advertisement type. You should also create some kind of api to interact from the frontend to your backend

Comment: @Eyescream, would that root node appear in the backoffice or front-end? I want the editor to act as an Umbraco User and put content from back-office, not as a site member.

Comment: I can create the apis, that's not problem, but can I use umbraco content as my entities? or should I create my own data tables and implement everything on my own?

Comment: That root node would appear only in the backoffice if you don't assign a template to it. You can surely use the umbraco nodes as entities, we do that regularly